# I'm trying to use a while loop to take user input and insert into an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

So im trying to take userResponse from prompt, convert it into an integer, then take that response and add it to my total. As long as my total is under 35 it should keep looping. Once the total userResponse has reached 35, the userResponse should be pushed into shoppingCart array and then the loop should break and an alert appear that they have reached the threshhold of 35. (btw sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, excuse my newbieness).

```js
//==== VARIABLES ========
let shoppingCart = [];
let shippingThreshhold = 35; 
let userResponse;
let total;

//==== LOGIC ========

//CHECK FOR ITEMS UNTIL THRESHOLD IS MET.
while (total < shippingThreshhold){
  
  //GET ITEM COST FROM USER
  let userResponse = prompt("What is the value of the item you have selected?");

  //CONVERT USER INPUT TO A NUMBER
  userResponse.parseInt();

  //ADD ITEM COST TO RUNNING TOTAL VARIABLE
  let total = shippingThreshhold - userResponse

  //PUSH ITEM COST TO CART ARRAY
  userResponse.concat(shoppingCart);
}

//SEND POPUP MESSAGE TO USER
alert("Your shipping for this order will be free!");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question doesn't exactly meet the [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it doesn't show sufficient research or explain the issue clearly - but I've still attempted to help you out in my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You need to initialize `total`
2. You don't add item cost to `total` properly
3. You don't parse the `userResponse` using `parseInt` properly
4. You don't push `userResponse` to the `shoppingCart` properly
5. There's no reason to declare `userResponse` globally.

Some improvements you could also make:

1. No need to store the `total`, as you can use the `shoppingCart` to calculate that (but I've kept `total` to keep it simpler).
2. Show the user their cart both as they go and at the end.
3. Format the `shippingThreshold` constant using a conventional naming format for constants (all caps separated by underscore).
4. Use `const` instead of `let` when possible, to avoid unintentionally overwriting variable values.
5. Handle edge cases.

```js
//==== VARIABLES ========
const shoppingCart = [];
const SHIPPING_THRESHOLD = 35;
let total = 0;

//==== LOGIC ========

//CHECK FOR ITEMS UNTIL THRESHOLD IS MET.
while (total < SHIPPING_THRESHOLD) {
  
  //GET ITEM COST FROM USER
  const userResponse = prompt(`Your cart: ${shoppingCart.length ? shoppingCart : 'empty' }. What is the value of the item you have selected?`);
  
  if (userResponse === null) {
    break
  } else {
    //CONVERT USER INPUT TO A NUMBER
    const itemCost = parseInt(userResponse);
    
    if (Number.isNaN(itemCost)) {
      alert(`"${userResponse}" is not a number please try again or press cancel to exit.`)
    } else {
      // ADD TO TOTAL
      total += itemCost

      //PUSH ITEM COST TO CART ARRAY
      shoppingCart.push(itemCost);
    }
  }
}

//SEND POPUP MESSAGE TO USER
if (total >= SHIPPING_THRESHOLD) {
  alert(`Your shipping for this order will be free! Your cart: ${shoppingCart}`);
} else {
  alert("Thanks for visiting!")
}
```

Comment: Hey so I got it working. I just had to follow specific rules because its for a school assignment, but i had one more issue: my alert box pops up even if i cancel the prompt. how do I make it so that it only shows if the total  is equal to 35 or more.

Comment: I've added some edge case handling, does that help? Btw you can test the snippet right here on SO by pressing "Run code snippet".